# javascript instanceOf explanation

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I am just playing with the instanceof operator. I want to know whether my understanding is correct or not

```
var C = function(){};
// in the above statement C has a "prototype" property which points to an object which has 
// the constructor property which points to C constructor
var o1 = new C();
// in above statement o1.__proto__ is points to C.prototype. that means inheriting from C.prototype.
console.log(o1 instanceof C) // returns true
//instanceof will check o1.__proto__ is equals to C.prototype(recursively until it finds null object).
C.prototype = {};
console.log(o1 instanceof C) // false;
in the above case o1 was inherited from C.prototype which points to the different object not the present C.prototype object (empty object). so the instanceof condition check fails hence its false.
```

please tell me if my interpretation is wrong

Comment: Your understanding seems correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, instanceof checks the constructors in the prototype chain of an object and returns true if the passed constructor is found anywhere in the chain. So if you destroy the prototype of a function, as you do by overwriting it with an empty object, then instanceof will always return false.